# cpp unit library not found test compilation might fail -ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, cppunit

I wanted to create a cppUnit Test in netbeans but however it states

```
cpp unit library not found test compilation might fail
```

I have tried this command

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libcppunit-dev
```

but it stil shows

```
cpp unit library not found test compilation might fail
```

what should I do to get rid of it?

I am using ubuntu ver 13.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [Step by step instructions for getting cppunit up and running with Netbeans 7.2 on OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666755/step-by-step-instructions-for-getting-cppunit-up-and-running-with-netbeans-7-2-o)

Comment: @RobinGreen I wonder how is that duplicate when his OS is MAC and mine is ubuntu

Comment: sure but the instructions should work if you ignore the XCode stuff.

Comment: I am having another problem again. after installing the warning message disappears but my netbeans cannot find those include file that is <cppunit/>. any ideas of what should I do?

Comment: They were probably installed into `/usr/local/include` instead of `/usr/include`.

Comment: I checked my /usr/include has nth but I did see that my /usr/local/lib contains some libcppunit files

Comment: What about /usr/local/include? I think the header files should be there.

Comment: i don't see any cppunit header files as well. am i missing out anything?

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal and try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

thus you can compile cpp codes in terminal.